# Document your c/c++ code in Wikimedia format or atleast in HTML

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, documentation, wiki

Is there a great way to export your c/c++ API's to Wikimedia format using Eclipse IDE or Eclipse IDE plugin? I am using Eclipse IDE c/c++ Luna version 4.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doxygen can output html and uses special comment mark-up to generate API documentation.